# Registration ID limit in User Notifications of Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When an app is reinstalled or upgraded, the gcm registration id is obtained from the GCM servers. When this id is added to the User Notification Key, will it be part of the 20 registration id limit or should the server de-register the old id and add the new id?

Answer (score 0):

Once a new Registration ID is issued by the GCM servers, you can overwrite the old one with it. There is no need to keep the old one any more. As a matter of fact you should not use the old one any more to send push notifications. If you do, it will still work, but you will get back a Canonical ID in the JSON response. That ID is the latest Registration ID for the device that you should be using. Take a look at the Canonical IDs section here:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#reg

Comment: For user notifications the documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#response-send) says that it'll give only the count in case of failures and not the canonical id. How will I know which id has failed?

Comment: If it fails it will return both the number of failed reg id's and the Registration IDs themselves (look at that same link). Here is the JSON fomat: {
  "success":1,
  "failure":2,
  "failed_registration_ids":[
     "regId1",
     "regId2"
  ]
} The failed_registration_ids array holds all failed Registration IDs. If you get any IDs here it is safe to delete them from your server. Those users most likely uninstalled your app. If they ever re-install, the app will re-register them and they will get new Registration IDs.

Answer (score 0):

As User Notifications is different functionality from GCM client registration, you need to [remove](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#remove) the earlier RegistrationId attached to this "User Notification Key" and then invoke an [add](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#add) with the new RegistrationId.

Comment: How will I know which id to remove? The canonical ids wont have that mapping. Should I map the registration id with device id in the db on my server?